# Subset the data based on different values present on same day

Tags: r

I have a following DF (demo). I would like to subset the data only for those IDs present on same Date with different City.

| ID | DATE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-07-08 | AAA |
| ABC | 2022-07-22 | BBB |
| XYZ | 2022-07-09 | CCC |
| XYZ | 2022-07-09 | YYY |
| PQR | 2022-09-22 | FFF |
| PQR | 2022-09-26 | EEE |
| EFG | 2022-10-03 | AAA |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | KKK |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | PPP |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | QQQ |

Desired Output:

| ID | DATE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2022-07-09 | CCC |
| XYZ | 2022-07-09 | YYY |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | KKK |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | PPP |
| EFG | 2022-10-16 | QQQ |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` ID and DATE and keep groups that have more than 1 `n_distinct` CITY:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, DATE) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(CITY) > 1)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   ID, DATE [2]
  ID    DATE       CITY 
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>
1 XYZ   2022-07-09 CCC  
2 XYZ   2022-07-09 YYY  
3 EFG   2022-10-16 KKK  
4 EFG   2022-10-16 PPP  
5 EFG   2022-10-16 QQQ
```

Comment: Excellent. "n_distinct" is the key.